# Integrating ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity and authentication with ServiceStack 4

Tags: servicestack, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have recently created web services using authentication and roles through ServiceStack 4 including openId and OAuth providers Google, Twitter and LinkedIn backed by a MongoDB repository.

I would like to integrate those services with my ASP.NET 5 MVC website that currently uses Microsoft's new Identity (OWIN) framework with the same providers for registration, authentication and roles.

I would prefer to use ServiceStack for authentication, registration and roles and have my MVC Controllers authorize against that.  I've read the posts regarding `SimpleMembership` and the wiki around Authorization and Session Handling in ServiceStack.

What I would like to know is if there is a starter template or example that takes the latest MVC 5 template and replaces/integrates that with ServiceStack 4.

Specifically, how does the existing `AccountController`, `IdentityUser`, `UserManager` and `UserStore` get replaced/modified to use ServiceStack?

Answer (score 1):

> What I would like to know is if there is a starter template or example that takes the latest MVC 5 template and replaces/integrates that with ServiceStack 4.

[ServiceStackVS](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStackVS) is an extension which allows to create ServiceStack powered projects from scratch. There is a template for ASP.NET MVC 5.

> Specifically, how does the existing AccountController, IdentityUser, UserManager and UserStore get replaced/modified to use ServiceStack?

Specifically, all of your controllers need to inherit from `ServiceStackController<T>` (where `T` is `IAuthSession`).
in your Global.asax's `Application_Start` you need to initialize your AppHost.
Then, you have something like that

```
public class MyAppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public MyAppHost() : base("My Service Name")
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        // Configure your container here (authentication, plugins...)
    }
}

public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    private MyAppHost AppHost { get; set; }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //...
        AppHost = new MyAppHost(this).Init();
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(AppHost.Container));
        //...
    }
}
```